# Blackberry ads on J2me GameCanvas

Tags: blackberry, java-me, ads, gamecanvas

I want to add blackberry ads on my `GameCanvas`. But we can only show the Blackberry ads on Blackberry `MainScreen`. Is there any way to show the ads on `GameCanvas`?

Answer (score 2):

If Banner class is not final (I don't have API docs) I think you can try in this way:

1. Create banner field object and resize it for your particular frame
2. Create RIM graphics with corresponded size Bitmap
3. Every Canvas repaint call paint of Banner field (it's protected so you need to extend Banner)
4. Draw Bitmap pixel on your canvas particular frame

It's just idea. There could be other hidden required calls like simulate adding field to screen, call setVisible, etc. And I'm 90% sure that Banner is final.

So it's 90% impossible I think :)